# How can I translate this SQL query on a subset into Django

Tags: python, mysql, django, subset

I have a MySQL table structured like this:

```
customer product
    1       10
    1       20
    1       30
    2       10
    2       30
    3       10
    3       20
    3       40
    4       10
    4       40
    4       50
    4       60
```

And I'd like to return all of the `customer`s associated with a subset of a particular list of `product`s. For example, if my query `product` IDs are `(10, 20 30)`, I want customers `1` and `2` since their products are a subset of my list, but not `3` because `40` isn't in my list even though `10` and `20` are.

My query `product` IDs will typically be 3 - 20 entries long but there will be hundreds or thousands of different products possible.

I can do this in raw SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM customer c
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM cp_table j AND c.id=j.customer_id
            AND j.product_id NOT IN (10,20,30)
);
```

But is there an easy way to construct such a query in Django? I'm using MySQL so I can't (apparently) use `distinct` on a particular column.

My Django `models.py` file is essentially:

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    products = models.ManyToManyField(Product, through='ProductList')

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class ProductList(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
```

EDIT: OK, I've found a way thanks to some of the comments and answers below:

```
subset_list = [10,20,30]
products_subset = Product.objects.filter(id__in=subset_list)
complement = Product.objects.exclude(id__in=subset_list)

c = Customer.objects.filter(products__in=products_subset)\
                    .exlude(products__in=complement).distinct()
```

However, I have my doubts about this method: it makes three queries (or perhaps doesn't, depending on how the QuerySet is evaluated) and the `complement` queryset is likely to be quite large. Is there a better way?

Comment: Please show the models.py file.

Comment: @Vingtoft I've added the essentials: it's a many-to-many relation.